# Assign Value to <input> inside <td> using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an `<input type="text" value="0.00" id="prdtotal"/>` inside a `<td>` in a table.

I want to use Javascript to compute a value and assign it to the textbox. How can I do it?

I tried using `document.getElementById("prdtotal").value="1.00";` but it doesnt work. Thanks for any help!

Comment: it seems like document.getElementById cannot find the <inpt> because it is inside a <td>

Comment: `document.getElementById` will find any element by id no matter how deeply nested inside other elements it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the value attribute:

```
document.getElementById("prdtotal").value = "1.00";
```

[document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) returns the actual DOM object (a handle/reference to the `<input>` element).

Also note your missing double quote before the closing parenthesis.

I would suggest you to take a look at the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) (MDN):

- [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement): a reference of all attributes a (general) HTML element can have.
- [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement): a reference of all special attributes an input element (e.g. `<textarea>`, `<input>`) can have.

Comment: Why does it not seem to woork for me?

Comment: @Umpong_1947676 What does not work for you? Which code did you use?

Comment: I am triggering  a change in the value of the textbox from a javascript called by a change in the value of another textbox. I tried the value to be passed on the second textbox(supposed to contain the answer) through an alert and it shows... however, whenever I pass the value to the text box using document.getElementById("prdtotal").value="2.00"; the value of the textbox does not change

Comment: @Umpong_1947676 Please post another question for that.

Comment: here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976216/document-getelementbyid-fails-to-update-textbox-value

Answer (score 2):

You've found the element using `getElementById` but you've not specified its the `value` property you want to set.

```
document.getElementById("prdtotal").value="1.00"
```

And a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/hevwt/

Comment: Oh, I just missed it in the post but i have it on my code...  although it still wont work... dont know what the problem is....