# document.getElementById fails to update textbox value

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a php code that generates table rows:

```
    <table id="listOfProducts" name="listOfProducts" width="100%">
    <tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Unit Price</th>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    Products on List: 2
    <tr class="row1" id="tr1">
    <td id="pid1">1</td>
    <td id="pname1">Paint Brush</td>
    <td id="pdesc1">Premium Brand </td>
    <td id="pprice1">24</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk1" checked></td>
    <td><input type="text" style="width:50px;" onkeyup="getall('tr1','ttp1')" id="1"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="ttp1" name="ttp1" value="00"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row1" id="tr2">
    <td id="pid2">2</td>
    <td id="pname2">Iron Nails</td>
    <td id="pdesc2">Stainless</td>
    <td id="pprice2">50</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk2" checked></td>
    <td><input type="text" style="width:50px;" onkeyup="getall('tr2','ttp2')" id="2"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="ttp2" name="ttp2" value="00"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

This successfully loads the values in the table and calls a javascript getall once the onkeyup function is called.

Here is the javascript code

```
    function getall( strId, prdno){
var tmpObj = document.getElementById(strId);
var myobj = $("#listOfProducts").find("tr#" + strId);
     alert("reported id for testing: " + tmpObj.getAttribute("id"));
 //alert (prdno);
    var prdid= myobj.find('td:eq(0)').text();
    var prdname= myobj.find('td:eq(1)').text();
    var prddesc= myobj.find('td:eq(2)').text();
var prduprice = parseFloat(myobj.find('td:eq(3)').text());
var quan = myobj.find('td:eq(5) input').val();
var ans=prduprice * quan;
document.getElementById(prdno).value=ans;       
    }
```

I don't know what's the real issue. I checked if the id of the containing textbox is successfully passed and it is...

Comment: The rendered html is always more useful when asking a javascript question.  (from browser's view source)

Comment: Does your console show any errors?

Comment: There is no error at all,

Comment: This works... check here: http://jsfiddle.net/pmwJd/

Comment: You need to place all your code inside `$(function(){ ..Here..   })`

Comment: Muy problem now is moving these checked table values to a php controller... how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using jquery to update it: `$('#'+prdno).val(ans);`

Comment: Hi there @Locohost, my problem now is to pass the checked values in the table to a php controller, probably, through an array. Do you have any suggestion? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Umpong_1947676: Sure. So you're catching a button click and grabbing the form values with jQuery. Next would be to use an ajax post to send the data to your server-side PHP script. You can find what you need here `http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/`

Comment: @Umpong_1947676: Or you could try this **[jQuery Form Plugin](https://github.com/malsup/form)**. Might be way easier, but I haven't tried it. I'll fiddle with this a bit after work today.

Comment: @Umpong_1947676: You should definitely go check it out. It's just some JS/jQuery code that wraps the messy bits of doing a form ajax post. It looked pretty simple.

Comment: @Umpong_1947676: Hey I just wanted to follow up here. I tried the jQuery Form Plugin (link is above) and it works great! I'm using it now for ajax file uploading. You have to provide your own server-side code, but that's the easy bit :-)

Comment: I'm having a problem passing the javascript values to my php controller... I posted another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073390/pass-javascript-variables-tp-php-controller-in-code-igniter

Answer (score 0):

i just copy and pasted your code and added the jquery include (v1.7.2) at the top and it totally works in Opera, FF and Chrome

Comment: i did thesame and it worked, what do you think is the problem on my code?

Comment: Do youthink it has something to do with the php values?

Comment: Oh yeah i found out, it's bout the arrangement of my script tags