# Pass Javascript Variables tp PHP Controller in Code Igniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Hi everyone I have this javascript that has to pass some variables including an array. My problem is that I cannot pass these values using the uRL because i might deal with many values. I am trying to use ajax JSON but i just cannot retrieve the values: Here is my javascript:

```
$(function(){
      $('#preview').click(function(){
         var thesum=0;
         var rowid=[];
         var rowfields=[];
             var supplier = document.getElementById("sid").value; //need to pass
             var terms=document.getElementById("terms").value; //need to pass

             var count = ($('#listOfProducts tr').length);
             //loop start
                var i=0;
                grid=$('#listOfProducts input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
                var $row = $(this).parents('tr'); 
                var $trid =$(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
                rowid[i]=$trid; 
                    rowfields.push({itemname: $row.find('td:eq(0)').text(), productname:$row.find('td:eq(1)').text(), productdesc: $row.find('td:eq(2)').text(), unitprice:$row.find('td:eq(3)').text(), quantity:$row.find('td:eq(5) input').val(), amount:$row.find('td:eq(6) input').val()});
                    i++;
                });//each close 
                var $tbldata=JSON.stringify(rowfields);//need to pass
                window.location = '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/main/retrievepo';// this is where i should get the passeddata
    });//preview click close
 });//function close
```

Here is my function, located in a PHP Controller (i am  using codeigniter)

```
public function retrievepo()
{
// should recieve data here
$this->load->view('PurchaseOrderPreview');
}
```

Any help please? I've been stacked from here for so long...

Comment: you need to use ajax if you want to pass the data from javascript to PHP

Comment: with in controller function, use post library to get the perameters

Comment: can you give me a fiddle of this guys... please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you try like this:

```
$(function(){
      $('#preview').click(function(){
         var thesum=0;
         var rowid=[];
         var rowfields=[];
         var supplier = document.getElementById("sid").value; //need to pass
         var terms=document.getElementById("terms").value; //need to pass

         var count = ($('#listOfProducts tr').length);
         //loop start
            var i=0;
            grid=$('#listOfProducts input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
            var $row = $(this).parents('tr'); 
            var $trid =$(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
            rowid[i]=$trid; 
                rowfields.push({itemname: $row.find('td:eq(0)').text(), productname:$row.find('td:eq(1)').text(), productdesc: $row.find('td:eq(2)').text(), unitprice:$row.find('td:eq(3)').text(), quantity:$row.find('td:eq(5) input').val(), amount:$row.find('td:eq(6) input').val()});
                i++;
            });//each close 
            var tbldata=JSON.stringify(rowfields);//need to pass
     $.post('/index.php/main/retrievepo',{"tbldata" : tbldata},function(response) 
     {
           //Load the response here to any div after ajax call     
           //Eg: $('#div_id').html(response);
     });//preview click close
 });
});
```

PHP Controller:

```
<?
public function retrievepo()
{
// should recieve data here
$data= $this->input->post('tbldata');
//pass the received post variables to view and access them inside your view.php
  $this->load->view('PurchaseOrderPreview',$data);
 }
    ?>
```

Comment: i got this response in the div id i have specified `"[{\"itemname\":\"TSauce 250 mL\",\"productname\":\"Tomato Sauce\",\"productdesc\":\"Filipino Style\",\"unitprice\":\"24\",\"quantity\":\"1\",\"amount\":\"24\"},{\"itemname\":\"Tsauce 100 mL\",\"productname\":\"Tomato Sauce\",\"productdesc\":\"Filipino Style\",\"unitprice\":\"50\",\"quantity\":\"1\",\"amount\":\"50\"}]"` but how can i get this on my controller? Can i just call the controller function for the response?

Comment: I tried this in the controller, and it simply returns "false"
`public function retrievepo()
 {

  $data= $this->input->post('tbldata');
  $this->load->view('PurchaseOrderPreview');
  echo json_encode($data);
  //echo $jqueryVariable;
   
 }`

Comment: I want to assign the data to an array at the controller, can I do this?

Comment: Try this:
public function retrievepo() { $data= $this->input->post('tbldata'); echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
}

Comment: Thank you so much... now my problem is to store this in an array

Comment: it returns this `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [itemname] =>TSauce 250 mL
            [productname] => Tomato Sauce
            [productdesc] => Filipino Style
            [unitprice] => 24
            [quantity] => 0
            [amount] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [itemname] => TSauce 100 mL
            [productname] => Tomato Sauce
            [productdesc] => Filipino Style
            [unitprice] => 50
            [quantity] => 0
            [amount] => 0
        )

)`  ------ the array sructure. how can I get each data?

Comment: Use 'foreach', iterate the array and store it

Comment: last one follow-up dude... what if, I want to open a new page and not load the response in a <div>?

Comment: Use window.location.href = "controller.php?someData=" + data + "&someOtherData=" + otherData with the required GET params.