# put cell data from google sheet into html input box. google apps script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I want to put data of C5 into HTML input box. I just made function bb(). and I don't have idea next. plz help me.

```js
function bb(){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var value = sheet.getRange("C5").getValue();
   return value;;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>

<body>
   <form name="frm">
    <br>
       Number   :&nbsp
    <input type="text" name="Number" iD="reginum" size="4" / >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign Value to <input> inside <td> using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974914/assign-value-to-input-inside-td-using-javascript)

Comment: Use html templates or google.script.run See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for Html best practices

Comment: I tried this.      <script launguage = 'JAVASCRIPT'>
   document.getElementById('reginum').value= "google.script.run.bb()"; </script>  but didn't work. What should I do?

Comment: `script launguage` or `script language`?

Comment: Oh. Thank you. I modified it. but still didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use [Apps Script Scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#scriptlets) `</+ ... ?>`

This will allow you to evaluate the return values of Apps Script functions directly within your `html`.

***Simple sample:***

Code.gs

```
function doGet(){  
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index.html").evaluate();  
}

function bb(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var value = sheet.getRange("C5").getValue();
  return value;
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>

<body>
   <form name="frm">
    <br>
       Number   :&nbsp
    <input type="text" name="Number" iD="reginum" size="4" value=<?=bb()?>/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```